# ASP.Net MVC RouteAttribute Error with Route Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm getting a lot of different errors while trying to add Route mapping to a certain action!

I'm trying to get this route for `GET /Admin/Users/User/1`
and `POST /Admin/Users/User`

But sadly there is already a User property in Controller!
So i cannot use `public ActionResult User(long id)` because i need to hide the user property (that i need to keep because it's the IPrincipal of the Controller and i still get the same error).

Defining route this way :

```
// First in RouteConfig
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// Then i'm registering my Areas.
```

this controller is in Admin Areas.
UsersController : Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(Name = "User/{id:long}")]
public ActionResult GetUser(long id)
{
    var model = new UserViewModel
    {
        User = _usersService.GetUser(id),
        Roles = _rolesService.GetRoleDropdown()
    };

    return View("User");
}

[HttpPost]
[Route(Name = "User")]
public ActionResult GetUser(UserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _usersService.UpdateUserRoles(model.User);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View("User", model);
}
```

Here is the error i'm getting :

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult User(Int64)' in 'MyProjectName.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
```

I'm not sure to really understand what's wrong!

I checked this page that explain the attributes and i see nothing wrong 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

### EDIT 1

It still doesn't work, i changed my registration to

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here is my full controller code because now it doesn't work for my Index action that was not in the initial code.

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersService _usersService;
    private readonly IRolesService _rolesService;

    public UsersController(
        IUsersService usersService,
        IRolesService rolesService)
    {
        _usersService = usersService;
        _rolesService = rolesService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route(Name = "Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UsersViewModel
        {
            Users = _usersService.GetUsers()
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route(Name = "User/{id:long}")]
    public new ActionResult User(long id)
    {
        var model = new UserViewModel
        {
            User = _usersService.GetUser(id),
            Roles = _rolesService.GetRoleDropdown()
        };

        return View("User");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route(Name = "User")]
    public new ActionResult User(UserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _usersService.UpdateUserRoles(model.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View("User", model);
    }
}
```

Now, i'm getting while trying to go to my index action:

> The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type
>   EspaceBiere.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult User(Int64) on type
>   EspaceBiere.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   User(EspaceBiere.Web.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Users.UserViewModel) on
>   type EspaceBiere.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController

and this while trying to go to User Action

> A public action method 'User' was not found on controller
>   'EspaceBiere.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController'.

And my link to the index action was :

tried with   `/Admin/Users`   for my `Index` Action

tried with   `/Admin/Users/User/1`   for `User` Action

### EDIT 2

Ok, my index is now working perfectly, but my user action still is not working!
I've removed all the Name properties of the RouteAttribute to keep them in the constructor (as template)  ->         [Route("User/{id:long}")]

Sorry, if i didn't see them on first read!

Here is the link to the action

```
                    <a href="@Url.Action("User", "Users", new { Area = "Admin", id = user.UserId })" class="btn btn-warning">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </a>
```

Here is the error

```
No matching action was found on controller 'EspaceBiere.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController'. This can happen when a controller uses RouteAttribute for routing, but no action on that controller matches the request.
```

It does work if i write in the URL   /Admin/Users/User/1
So how should i write my Url.Action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't completely understood the concept of using attribute routing if that was your intention. Here is an example of how to configure the routes you wanted.

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : Controller {
    private readonly IUsersService _usersService;
    private readonly IRolesService _rolesService;

    public UsersController(
        IUsersService usersService,
        IRolesService rolesService) {
        _usersService = usersService;
        _rolesService = rolesService;
    }

    //GET Admin/Users
    //GET Admin/Users/Index
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var model = new UsersViewModel {
            Users = _usersService.GetUsers()
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    //GET Admin/Users/User/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("User/{id:long}", Name = "GetUser")]
    public ActionResult GetUser(long id) {
        var model = new UserViewModel {
            User = _usersService.GetUser(id),
            Roles = _rolesService.GetRoleDropdown()
        };

        return View("User");
    }

    //POST Admin/Users/User
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("User")]
    public ActionResult PostUser(UserViewModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            _usersService.UpdateUserRoles(model.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View("User", model);
    }
}
```

> If you are using both Areas with route attributes, and areas with
>   convention based routes (set by an AreaRegistration class), then you
>   need to make sure that area registration happen after MVC attribute
>   routes are configured, however before the default convention-based
>   route is set. The reason is that route registration should be ordered
>   from the most specific (attributes) through more general (area
>   registration) to the mist generic (the default route) to avoid generic
>   routes from “hiding” more specific routes by matching incoming
>   requests too early in the pipeline.

```
// First in RouteConfig
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

// Then register Areas.
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

> **Route Names**
>
> You can specify a name for a route, in order to easily allow URI
>   generation for it. For example, for the following route:

```
[Route("User/{id:long}", Name = "GetUser")]
public ActionResult GetUser(long id)
```

you could generate a link using **Url.RouteUrl**:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("GetUser", new { Area = "Admin", id = user.UserId })" class="btn btn-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Stop settings `Name` in the attribute. That is only used for generating urls. Look at the way i did it in my example. You can clearly see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Added an other Edit we are near the answer but still the User Route doesn't act as i want!

Comment: @Vince, like i said before, the `Route.Name` is used to generate URL like how you wanted to use it but you were using `Name` to try to set the route template. Didn't know you were trying to generate the URL as well. Check updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Nice,

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("User")]
    public ActionResult PostUser(UserViewModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            _usersService.UpdateUserRoles(model.User);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }enter code here

        return View("User", model);
    }
```

Comment: please clarify your answer