# No action was found on the controller 'Department' that matches the name 'DeleteDepartments'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have managed to get a list , get a single list, edit and insert data (GET, GET id, INSERT, PUT work but DELETE doesn't work) into SQL server database but I am getting an error while deleting id. I have tested in postman but delete request giving me such error:

I am using data model to extract model from database

{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:62333/api/Department/DeleteDepartments/13'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Department' that matches the name 'DeleteDepartments'."
}

What is the reason Delete is not working ?

DepartmentController.cs

```cs
[HttpDelete]
[Route("DeleteDepartments")]

public IHttpActionResult DeleteDepartment(int id)
{
    //int empId = Convert.ToInt32(id);  
    Department department = objEntity.Departments.Find(id);
    if (department == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    objEntity.Departments.Remove(department);
    objEntity.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(department);
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```cs
   
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new
              {
                  id = RouteParameter.Optional,
              });

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
       new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

    EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

Comment: Your error is nothing to do with SQL Server so I have untagged it.

Comment: Does [ASP.NET MVC Route Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176031/390122) help?